# django rest framework: hypelinking referenced entitites

Tags: python, django, rest, hyperlink, django-rest-framework

In my project i expose all BlogArticle entities via public API using Django rest framework.

Each BlogArticle ha an `author` field that refers to a Django user. I want this relations to be modeled using hyperlinks.

to achieve this i added:

in urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'blogarticles', BlogArticleViewSet)
```

in views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class BlogArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BlogArticle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogArticleSerializer
```

in serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')

class BlogArticleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-detail', format='json')
    class Meta:
        model = BlogArticle
        fields = ('title', 'blog_content', 'author')
```

everything works correctly but not the hyperlink url.

The result is this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "count": 21, 
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogarticles/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "text", 
            "blog_content": "content", 
            "author": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/"
        }, 
        {
            "title": "boh", 
            "blog_content": "aa", 
            "author": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/"
        }, 
    [---]
```

First 2 BlogArticles apparently are written by 2 different users but the user is always the same(as conseguence by calling the second url i get a 404 response).

What i'm expecting is this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "count": 21, 
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogarticles/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "text", 
            "blog_content": "content", 
            "author": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/"
        }, 
        {
            "title": "boh", 
            "blog_content": "aa", 
            "author": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/"
        }, 
    [---]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to hyperlink against related objects, you should use `HyperlinkedRelatedField`. When you need to hyperlink against the current object (the `url` field on the serializer), you should use `HyperlinkedIdentityField`.

```
class BlogArticleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', format='json')

    class Meta:
        model = BlogArticle
        fields = ('title', 'blog_content', 'author')
```